How to Connect Ezcad2 with a Remote Database via TCP/IP for Laser Engraving
I am trying to connect my laser engraver to a remote database using Ezcad2 software. The goal is for the laser engraver to retrieve strings from the database. I attempted to use the TCP/IP communication feature in Ezcad2, but I'm encountering some issues.
In the Ezcad2 TCP/IP settings, there are only three textboxes available:
IP address
Port
Command
However, I am unsure where to input the username and password for the database connection.
How can I input the database's username and password in Ezcad2?
What is the correct way to configure Ezcad2 for communication with a remote database?
Any guidance or examples
of how to set up this connection would be greatly appreciated.
